# can't create folder in /mnt/sdcard

Tags: android

I think I'm doing everything right to first create a folder
that I can write to later in my app, but it doesn't seem to be working.
Any clues as to how I've failed?

It correctly tries to create /mnt/sdcard/gradebook

I have uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
in my manifest. I'm running on a real device (Samsung Galaxy S) and I'm not using the
sdcard as storage while its attached to my computer.

```
    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // We can read and write the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        // We can only read the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        Toast.makeText(this,"This Application needs a writable external storage (sdcard).",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    } else {
        // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
        //  to know is we can neither read nor write
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        Toast.makeText(this,"This Application needs a mounted external storage (sdcard).",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();

    }


    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () + "/gradeBook");
    boolean success = false;
    if(!folder.exists()){
         success = folder.mkdir();
    }
    if (!success) {
        Log.e("FILE", "can't create " + folder);
    }
    else 
    {
        Log.i("FILE", "directory is created"); 
    }
```

Here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="com.ulsanonline.gradebook" 
    android:versionName="@string/version" 
    android:installLocation="auto" 
    android:versionCode="2">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"></uses-sdk> 
    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:debuggable="true" 
        android:persistent="false" 
        android:hasCode="true"
        android:minSdkVersion="8">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".CourseWork" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have the disk mounted on your computer? You'll get permission denied if you try to write to a disk that's connected to a PC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`uses-permission` must be placed directly as `<manifest>` child, so it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="com.ulsanonline.gradebook" 
    android:versionName="@string/version" 
    android:installLocation="auto" 
    android:versionCode="2">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"></uses-sdk> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:debuggable="true" 
        android:persistent="false"
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks very much....but the camera worked where it was placed without causing problems, what's up with that?

Comment: perhaps because my app doesn't control the camera and is merely passing off to an unnamed activity to take a picture. I use Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); rather than anything within my packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
//Declare a string 

String NewFolder = "/myNewFolder";
String extStorageDirectory;

//external storage directory path
    extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();    
//creating a new folder
File mkTarDir=new File(extStorageDirectory + NewFolder);
  mkTarDir.mkdir();
//path to save a image              
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory + NewFolder ,"myimage"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".PNG");
```